# Defining my indentation environment

Tags: indentation

I define my indentation environment as follows:

```
\newenvironment{myindentpar}[1]%
 {\begin{list}{}%
         {\setlength{\leftmargin}{#1}}%
         \item[]%
 }
 {\end{list}}
```

Here is a minimal example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstloadlanguages{[5.2]Mathematica}

\newenvironment{myindentpar}[1]%
 {\begin{list}{}%
         {\setlength{\leftmargin}{#1}}%
         \item[]%
 }
 {\end{list}}

\begin{document}

We start by defining the Langrangian (or material) description of the motion. We also provide the displacement field. 
\begin{myindentpar}{2cm}
\begin{lstlisting}
T[X_, Y_, Z_] = {X + Y Tan[\[Gamma]], Y, Z};
u[X_, Y_, Z_] = T[X, Y, Z] - {X, Y, Z};
\end{lstlisting}
\end{myindentpar}
Let consider a unit square.

\end{document}
```

How can I get rid of the spacing between the listing and the text above it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two sourced for the big vertical space: `\topsep` and the fact that `lstlistings` after `\item[]` will start a new line.

You're using the wrong tool, the `xleftmargin` option does the job.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstloadlanguages{[5.2]Mathematica}

\lstset{% sorry, I can't stand listings in any different fashion
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  columns=fullflexible,
  keepspaces,
}

\newenvironment{myindentpar}[1]%
 {\begin{list}{}%
         {\setlength{\leftmargin}{#1}}%
         \item[]%
 }
 {\end{list}}

\begin{document}

We start by defining the Langrangian (or material) description of 
the motion. We also provide the displacement field. 
\begin{myindentpar}{2cm}
\begin{lstlisting}
T[X_, Y_, Z_] = {X + Y Tan[\[Gamma]], Y, Z};
u[X_, Y_, Z_] = T[X, Y, Z] - {X, Y, Z};
\end{lstlisting}
\end{myindentpar}
Let consider a unit square.

We start by defining the Langrangian (or material) description of 
the motion. We also provide the displacement field. 
\begin{lstlisting}[xleftmargin=2cm]
T[X_, Y_, Z_] = {X + Y Tan[\[Gamma]], Y, Z};
u[X_, Y_, Z_] = T[X, Y, Z] - {X, Y, Z};
\end{lstlisting}
Let consider a unit square.

\end{document}
```

[image]